# How to pass variables in the game engine to a newly loaded .blend?

Tags: python, game-engine

I have two blend files, a.blend and b.blend.

I open a.blend, and run the game engine <kbd>P</kbd>. A script is then run that uses the function `bge.logic.startGame("b.blend")`, which starts running the game setup in b.blend.

In b.blend, another script runs. This one needs a value that is in a script in a.blend. How can I pass a var from a script in a.blend to the script in b.blend?

Answer (score 2):

You could dump it to a file.

a.blend

```
with open('/tmp/mydata', 'w') as f:
    f.write(a_setting)
```

b.blend

```
with open('/tmp/mydata', 'r') as f:
    b_setting = f.read()
```

Comment: Eh.... that is really inefficient, I did think of doing that already. I wonder it it could be passed more efficiently via an external source though.

Comment: As you start your game session just once, it "just" increases loading time a bit when starting. A typical game has a save(load option already, so you might use it for such a purpose as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

As the name implies, you start a brand new game session. The sessions have no relationship to each other (except the starting operation). Each session starts from scratch.

Comment: So what exactly should I do in this scenario?