# Blender Game Engine - Load Scene Similar To Linked

Tags: python, game-engine, linked-data

Lets say have have two files a.blend and b.blend. Inside both blends are two different game engine scenes. Both have animations, objects, logic, scripts, constrained objects and armatures.

From b.blend, I wan't to **dynamically** load the scene into a.blend, and switch two it.

For reference, this could be done statically by linking the scene in, and then using `scene.replace("sceneB")`

By the way, Start Game From File is [*not* an option](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/40806/3127)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LibLoad()](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_2/bge.logic.html#bge.logic.LibLoad). It merges the data of a blend file into the current scene. So you could switch/add an hard-coded nearly empty scene and dynamically LibLoad() the data from the other blend file. The flexible part is the name of the blend file.